# Fill space with empty hyperlink

Tags: html, css

I want to click on HTML table cell and open new page. The solution is working fine if I have text into table sell. But if I have empty cell there is no hyperlink.

```
tr.clickable td a {
    display: block;
    background: green;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

How I can fill the cell space with the empty hyperlink?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? or share all your code?

Comment: If you have another row, try giving a min-height.

Comment: Add dimensions to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
tr.clickable td a {
display: block;
background: green;
text-decoration:none;
}
tr.clickable td a:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr class="clickable">
<td>
  <a href=""></a>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### another solution

You can use `:empty` pseudo element.

```
tr.clickable td a:empty{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem. Is there any more clean and simple solution?

Comment: one more solution added

Answer (score 0):

You can give it fixed `min-height` and `min-width`, for example:

```
tr.clickable td a {
   display: block;
   background: green;
   text-decoration:none;
   min-width:10px;
   min-height:10px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution is to use the [**CSS content property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) with `before` or `after` pseudo elements, by adding `content: "\200B";`, like this:

```css
tr.clickable td a {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  text-decoration: none;
}
tr.clickable td a::before {
  content: "\200B";
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr class="clickable">
    <td>
      <a href=""></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is solving the problem partially. Can you propose some other solution?

Comment: @FastWalker you can also give it a padding for example : `padding:5px`, but this will affect it when it has content, or simply when it doesn't have content just put on it a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`.

Comment: I tried to use &nbsp; but I use Java Server Faces. And again I see empty cell without link.

Comment: Can you propose some more simple solution to @afelixj? His solution is working but looks like a hack to me.

Comment: @FastWalker Ok, just use the solution on my EDIT.

Comment: Just to be sure is there any other solution?

Comment: @FastWalker AFAIK, these are all the possible solutions, I even searched for it and that's all I found.